Serilog - Read and combine multiple log files
We are writing to multiple log files with Serilog. We do this to prevent that we have one big file (to make it more digestible) and that every service has its own dedicated log file. The downside is that we need to look in many files to understand if something went wrong or make it more difficult to follow chronologically what happened if the information is spread over multiple files. To make this easier we would like the ability to easily merge a selection of files (and optionally filter on event level).
File1
2024-11-07 15:16:32.664 [ERR] Error line from file 1
This line has a newline.
2024-11-07 16:55:39.804 [INF] Information logging from file 1
2024-11-07 17:13:12.624 [ERR] Another error line from file 1

File2
2024-11-07 14:40:27.640 [ERR] Error line from file 2
2024-11-07 17:05:09.104 [INF] Information logging from file 2
2024-11-07 17:23:22.240 [ERR] Another error line from file 2

Result of combining File1 and File2 could look something like this
2024-11-07 14:40:27.640 [ERR] File2|Error line from file 2
2024-11-07 15:16:32.664 [ERR] File1|Error line from file 1
This line has a newline.
2024-11-07 16:55:39.804 [INF] File1|Information logging from file 1
2024-11-07 17:05:09.104 [INF] File2|Information logging from file 2
2024-11-07 17:13:12.624 [ERR] File1|Another error line from file 1
2024-11-07 17:23:22.240 [ERR] File2|Another error line from file 2

Is there a library out there that could do this, or should we use a different library or method to write logging to make this possible?

I would recommend to use something like Seq ( https://datalust.co/seq ). It does support the Serilog so not much code changes and also allows you to filter the logs and more.  I am not sure which .Net version you are using but you can try .Net Aspire as well.

Thanks for your suggestions @ChinmayT. Seq is for us probably an overkill as analyzing the log files would only be needed when investigating issues on the system for which the problem happened (we have many systems). Using .Net Aspire is currently not an option. This is related to how our systems are currently build. Typically, we would copy over the log files (we don't always have direct access to the systems) and analyze them (can be automatic and manually).
